# rails simple-form empty json fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, simple-form

I've been trying new things/looking for answers for days now, hoping someone can help.

I have a column in my db with a JSON attribute. The json starts out empty and users can input whatever key, value pairs they want and can add more if pairs if needed

model: Model,
attribute: resources

My 'edit' form looks like this right now:

```
 - @model.resources.each do |k,v|
   = text_field_tag "model[resources][#{k}]", k 
   = text_field_tag "model[resources][#{k}]", v
```

which displays the key, value pairs correctly.

I've tried the same code for my 'add new' form, but I get an error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

It seems like I need the json to be populated in order for this code to work, but I need it to start out as blank inputs.

Any thoughts on how to get this forms to work? Or maybe there's a different, better way to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a dynamic attribute, you could do the following:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :resources do |r| %>
    <%= r.input key, :input_html => { :value => <value> } %>
<% end %>
```

Source:  https://gist.github.com/lucasdavila/3715290